# ThreeJS - Intersection of a line and sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two objects on my scene: a red line and a sphere.

While camera rotating/zooming/moving, I need to check the following:

- Does the line intersects with the sphere looking from the current position of the camera (please see images below)? Please use [this JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxK63/7/) that creates the scene on the images.

I know how to find the intersection between the current mouse position and objects on the scene (just [like this example](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html) shows).

But how to do this in my case?

[image: does not intersect]

[image: intersect]

JS Fiddle Code:

```
    /**
     * PREPARE SCENE
     */
    var mouse = {
        x : 0,
        y : 0
    };

    var projector = new THREE.Projector();

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,
            window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    camera.position.x = -5;
    camera.position.y = 5;
    camera.position.z = 30;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera,
            renderer.domElement);

    controls.rotateSpeed = 3.0;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.5;
    controls.panSpeed = 1.0;

    controls.staticMoving = true;

    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(20, 5);
    scene.add(grid);

    /**
     * CREATE SPHERE
     */
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 10, 10),
            new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
    sphere.overdraw = true;
    scene.add(sphere);

    /**
     * CREATE LINE
     */
    var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color : 0xFF0000
    });
    var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(8, 8, 8));
    lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(8, 8, 20));
    var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
     scene.add(line);


    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', render, false);
    render();

    function render(event) {

        var mouse = {};

        /*
         * INTERSECTION
         */
        if (event != null) {
            //intersection job???
        }
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution that is pretty simple (of course). See [new JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxK63/8/) that checks intersection of the line and sphere and visualizes the ray for debugging.

[image]

The JS Fiddle code:

```
    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();
render();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 800;

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
    controls.panSpeed = 4;
    controls.noZoom = false;
    controls.noPan = false;
    controls.staticMoving = true;

    controls.addEventListener('change', render);

    // world

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneTarget = new THREE.Scene();

    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(500, 50);
        scene.add(grid);

     /**
     * CREATE LINE
     */
    var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color : 0xFF0000
    });
    var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 200, 100));
    lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(300, 200, 200));
    var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
     sceneTarget.add(line);

    /*
    * CREARE SPHERE
    */
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(150, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  sphere.overdraw = true;
  scene.add(sphere);

    // renderer

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true 
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);

     document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();

}

function render() {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    renderer.render(sceneTarget, camera);
    intersect();

}

function intersect() {

    var direction = new THREE.Vector3(100, 200, 100);

    var startPoint = camera.position.clone();

    var directionVector = direction.sub( startPoint );

    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(startPoint, directionVector.clone(). normalize());

    scene.updateMatrixWorld(); // required, since you haven't rendered yet

    var rayIntersects = ray.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

    if (rayIntersects[0]) {
        //inersection is found
        console.log(rayIntersects[0]);

        //visualize the ray for debugging
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
          color: 0x0000ff
        });
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(ray.ray.origin.x, ray.ray.origin.y, ray.ray.origin.z));
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 200, 100));
        var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
        sceneTarget.add( line );

    }

}
```