# Three.js - Drawing a large point at the intersection between camera direction and sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to draw a point (with a size visible) on a sphere with `three.js`. This point is at the intersection between the line started from the camera and the sphere.

I was inspired by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085224/threejs-intersection-of-a-line-and-sphere).

you can my result on [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/10hemttk/43/)

As you can see, I have hidden the `drawPointIntersection()` function which is called after `render()` function. this is in this function that I do instructions to draw this point.

Here's this part of code :

```
function drawPointIntersection() {

  // Direction of camera
  var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
  var startPoint = camera.position.clone();
  var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(startPoint, direction);  

  // Get point of camera direction  projected on sphere
  var rayIntersects = ray.intersectObject(scene, true);

  // Distance between camera and projected point
  console.log(rayIntersects[0]);

  // Draw point of camera direction on sphere
  var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  // Looking for right syntax with coordinates of intersection point

  //dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(rayIntersects[1]);
  //dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(rayIntersects.point.x, rayIntersects.point.y, rayIntersects.point.z);

  var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({size: 10, sizeAttenuation: false});
  var dot = new THREE.Points(dotGeometry, dotMaterial);
  scene.add(dot);
}
```

As you can see, I tried to use different syntax to get the coordinates of the point returned by `ray.intersectObject(scene, true)` but none works :

```
   dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

   dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(rayIntersects[1]);

   dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(rayIntersects.point.x, rayIntersects.point.y, rayIntersects.point.z);
```

I make you notice that camera is rotating around the sphere.

I don't know why it doesn't work, if someone could tell me how to get these coordinates in order to draw the point on the sphere with `THREE.Points` method with three.js R75.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The sphere is in world coordinate space (I think) and the camera's forward direction isnt necessarily (0,0,-1) in world coordinate space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in each frame changes the position of the camera, so the wrong direction vector. Try this:

```
// Camera position
var startPoint = camera.position.clone();

// Direction of camera
var direction = sphere.position.clone().sub(startPoint).normalize();
```

And just look at the intersection of the target object (sphere):

```
var rayIntersects = ray.intersectObject(sphere, true);
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/3wm9c0jf/ ]

Comment: @stob--  thanks ! that works ... and a final question, how can I avoid to draw a line but just a point while sphere is rotating ? I need to remove the point at each frame for having just a spot.

Comment: I solve this issue by adding a "scene.remove(dot)" after "renderer.render(scene, camera)" call.